# How to switch the colors of two categories in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say I use the following 'iris' example with scatterplots

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="muted")

# Load the example iris dataset
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# "Melt" the dataset to "long-form" or "tidy" representation
iris = pd.melt(iris, "species", var_name="measurement")

# Draw a categorical scatterplot to show each observation
sns.swarmplot(x="measurement", y="value", hue="species", data=iris)
```

which outputs the following plot:

[image]

But let's say I wanted to switch the colors between setosa and versicolor, making setosa green and versicolor blue, explicitly using the seaborn palette. I would try something like this:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="muted")
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris = pd.melt(iris, "species", var_name="measurement")
sns.swarmplot(x="measurement", y="value", hue="species", data=iris, palette=dict(setosa = 'g', versicolor = 'b', virginica = 'r'))
```

Naturally, this doesn't work:

[image]

The color palette is now off.

(1) How do you switch two categories keeping seaborn's colour palette?

(2) What is you wanted to chose another seaborn "standard" color, like cyan? How could I switch setosa from blue to cyan?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question as it looks like you have switched the colors of two categories.

Comment: @Virginica is the same. I was to take the original and switch "setosa" and "versicolor" with seaborn's original  color palette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seaborn is opensource: 
The hexcodes are listed here:
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/palettes.py

```
SEABORN_PALETTES = dict(
    deep=["#4C72B0", "#55A868", "#C44E52",
          "#8172B2", "#CCB974", "#64B5CD"],
    muted=["#4878CF", "#6ACC65", "#D65F5F",
           "#B47CC7", "#C4AD66", "#77BEDB"],
    pastel=["#92C6FF", "#97F0AA", "#FF9F9A",
            "#D0BBFF", "#FFFEA3", "#B0E0E6"],
    bright=["#003FFF", "#03ED3A", "#E8000B",
            "#8A2BE2", "#FFC400", "#00D7FF"],
    dark=["#001C7F", "#017517", "#8C0900",
          "#7600A1", "#B8860B", "#006374"],
    colorblind=["#0072B2", "#009E73", "#D55E00",
                "#CC79A7", "#F0E442", "#56B4E9"]
    )


sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="muted")
iris     = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris     = pd.melt(iris, "species", var_name="measurement")
muted    = ["#4878CF", "#6ACC65", "#D65F5F", "#B47CC7", "#C4AD66", "#77BEDB"]
newPal   = dict(setosa = muted[0], versicolor = muted[2], virginica = muted[1])
sns.swarmplot(x="measurement", y="value", hue="species", data=iris,palette=newPal )
```

[image]

Comment: It's not me voting down answers. I think this is correct.

Comment: Though, could you output the plot and paste above? That would certainly improve the post. Thanks!

Comment: In the code, you're switching versicolor and viriginia, but that's fine.